# Team System Web Access ADFS SSO

Tags: tfs, single-sign-on, adfs

I am now working on TFS 2010. And it has a built-in website called Team System Web Access. The Team System Web Access should be integrated with ADFS for the purpose of SSO support. Can anybody help show some solutions? Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question.  TFS 2010, 2012, and 2013 all have integration with Active Directory for security & identity.

Comment: If you're looking to configure ADFS for a federated authentication senario (authenticate to a different domain than TFS is hosted in), the only potential solution I've been able to find is integrating TFS with a SharePoint farm that is already configured to do so, the standalone install that TFS creates simply doesn't support this configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use single sign-on you can. As long as the connecting users end up with Active Directory credentials then they will be able to access TFS and the Web Access. This works for TFS 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, and 2013.

As Ed says, as long as calls to the TFS Web Portal or TFS itself is with the context of an active directory authenticated account that has permission it will work. How you receive your AD token is however you want to configure it. Certificate, smart card, login, or ADFS, its all the same to Windows.